# Add zeros to pandas column, based on amount set in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have one column with phone numbers (as strings). Then there is another column that gives me the amount of zeros (as int), that I would like to append to the existing phone number. What I want to do is something like (5 * "0" => "00000"). There is one more prerequisite. Zeros must only be added, if the phone number ends on "1".

```
Example:
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([["11", 2], ["21", 3], ["10", 6]], columns=['phone', 'ext_length'])

What I tried:
>>> df.loc[(df.phone.str.endswith("1")), "complete_phone"] = df.phone + (df.ext_length * "0")
```

While filtering the correct rows where phone ends on "1" and creating the column "complete_phone" works, I cannot get the "math" to work. I am getting

```
TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')
```

Neither do I understand the error message, nor do I have an idea, how to solve this.

PS: I was also looking for a link, where it shows how to properly include python examples, as I could see in other questions with [in:] and [out:] plus results. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) for replace if `True` of condition and 
[`str.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.repeat.html):

```
s = pd.Series(['0'], index=df.index)
mask = df.phone.str.endswith("1")
df["complete_phone"] = df.phone.mask(mask, df.phone + s.str.repeat(df.ext_length))
print (df)
  phone  ext_length complete_phone
0    11           2           1100
1    21           3          21000
2    10           6             10
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
mask = df.phone.str.endswith("1")
df["complete_phone"] = df['phone'].mask(mask, df.apply(lambda x: x['phone'] + 
                                                                 '0' * x.ext_length, axis=1))
print (df)
  phone  ext_length complete_phone
0    11           2           1100
1    21           3          21000
2    10           6             10
```

```
mask = df.phone.str.endswith("1")
df["complete_phone"] = df.phone.mask(mask, df['phone'] +
                                           df['ext_length'].apply(lambda x:'0'*x))
print (df)
  phone  ext_length complete_phone
0    11           2           1100
1    21           3          21000
2    10           6             10
```

Your solution is similar only get `NaN`s if mask is `False`:

```
mask = df.phone.str.endswith("1")
df.loc[mask, "complete_phone"] = df['phone'] + df.apply(lambda x: '0' * x.ext_length, axis=1)
  phone  ext_length complete_phone
0    11           2           1100
1    21           3          21000
2    10           6            NaN
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. I am still figuring out, what exactly you were doing. But I could apply it right away to my actual problem. I am using the str.repeat approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([["11", 2], ["21", 3], ["10", 6]], columns=['phone', 'ext_length'])

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
  phone  ext_length
0    11           2
1    21           3
2    10           6

In [4]: df['complete_phone'] = [number+'0'*length if number.endswith('1') else number for number, length in zip(df.phone, df.ext_length)]

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
  phone  ext_length complete_phone
0    11           2           1100
1    21           3          21000
2    10           6             10
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but I do not completely understand it (yet). It might help me with another issue in the same context though.

Comment: So the approach within the list comprehension on `In [4]:` @SLglider is to zip the two columns (`phone` and `ext_length`), then perform the check to see if there is a 1 at the end. If so, do the desired change to the number, if not, leave it alone. The result of this is then put into `complete_phone`, hope this helps ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the `apply` function comes in handy:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["11", 2], ["21", 3], ["10", 6]], columns=['phone', 'ext_length'])
df['complete_phone'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['phone'] + "0" * x['ext_length'], axis=1)
```